# How can I skip a value and go to the next one in fscanf(), and how can I fscanf() a specific type

Tags: c

How can I skip a value and go to the next one in `fscanf()`? For example I have the following data in my input file:

```
11112222
3.95
4
22.5
```

What I should do in order to scan the second value? (I want to skip 11112222 to scan 3.95)

And one more thing: if I want to `fscanf()` a specific data type, how can I do that? (Ex: I want to scan `double` value and skip the `int` value.)

Comment: You might want to think of using [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or perhaps
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read lines of data into a string variable, and then use
[`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) to parse the data on the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int fun() {
 int unusedvar;
 float value;
 FILE *fp=fopen("yourfilename","r");
 fscanf(fp,"%d%f",&unusedvar,&value);
 return 0;
}
```

Aint that simple?

Comment: Chris' answer is definitively better, you should use that: don't introduce complexity in your code by adding a variable that isn't used, and use a `double` variable for the real thing, since `double` is *the* floating point type that is expected almost everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `*` modifier to scan a value and throw it away rather than storing it.  For example:

```
if (scanf("%*d%lf", &var) != 1)
    …process input error…
```

will read the first two lines of your input file and store the value from the second into the double variable `var`